# How to find a particular element a replace it with another dynamically in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have been trying to add some custom features in tinymce editor. A button to highlight a text and the highlighted text should further be replaced with a underscore. This means that the mark element with it content should be replace with something like this:

```
<p>&nbsp;This yet another moment of trial. We <mark>keep</mark>doing it until it becomes <mark>perfect</mark>.</p>
```

To this:

```
<p>&nbsp;This yet another moment of trial. We <b>_____</b>doing it untill it becomes <b>____</b>.</p>
```

I have been trying it with this function

```
function getContentFromEditor() {
  var content = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
  content = content.replace("<mark>", "<b>______</b>");
  document.getElementById("content_display").innerHTML = content;
}
```

But it only change the start tag.

Comment: jQuery isn't the way to do this. TinyMCE has it's own methods for adding custom toolbar buttons. I'd strongly suggest you read the documentation: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/custom-toolbar-button/

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan,  i just need how to replace the MARK tags found in the paragraph using jquery or javascript.  i have already implemented the toolbar button successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the regex you need:

**[`/<mark>\[^<>\]*<\/mark>/g`](https://regex101.com/r/UaPbnH/1)**

So your code should be updated like this:

```
content = content.replace(/<mark>[^<>]*<\/mark>/g, "<b>______</b>");
```

**Demo:**

This is a sample Demo:

```js
var text = '<p>&nbsp;This yet another moment of trial. We <mark>keep</mark>doing it until it becomes <mark>perfect</mark>.</p>';

text = text.replace(/<mark>[^<>]*<\/mark>/g,"<b>______</b>");
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

After making content changes to the tinyMCE editor dynamically you have to call the save function to update it visually.

Depending on your version:
`tinymce.triggerSave();`
or
`tinymce.activeEditor.save();`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find all the marked elements.
And then loop over all those marked elements and replace them with the target HTML you want the elements to be replaced with

```js
var replaceWithStr = "<b>____</b>";
var markedElems = document.getElementsByTagName("mark");
var markedElemsArr = [].slice.call(markedElems);
markedElemsArr.forEach(function(elem){
  //elem.innerText = replaceWithStr; // this will only replace text
  //elem.innerHTML = replaceWithStr; // this will not remove the mark tag, so your underscore will still be highlighted
  elem.outerHTML = replaceWithStr; // this will give the required result
})
```

```html
<p>&nbsp;This yet another moment of trial. We <mark>keep</mark> doing it until it becomes <mark>perfect</mark>.</p>
```

Comment: Your answer is more advance. Thanks but @chsdk got me first. I am trying index of each mark element in the loop. I will like a user to input the missing text and i will then iterate over the original content based on the indices, to check if they matches. It is a Subjective stuff. Any further assistance?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using regular expressions:

```
 content = content.replace(/<mark>[a-zA-Z]*<\/mark>/g,"<b>______</b>");
```